# npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT on creating new project using ng new appname

Tags: angular, npm, timeout, socket-timeout-exception

Can somebody help me on this? i am getting following error:

Angular & Node version Installed

```
Angular CLI: 12.0.1
Node: 14.16.0
Package Manager: npm 7.11.2
OS: win32 x64
```

```
    D:\Learning\Angular>ng new working
    ? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
    ? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
    CREATE working/angular.json (3045 bytes)
    CREATE working/package.json (1069 bytes)
    CREATE working/README.md (997 bytes)
    CREATE working/tsconfig.json (783 bytes)
    CREATE working/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
    CREATE working/.gitignore (604 bytes)
    CREATE working/.browserslistrc (703 bytes)
    CREATE working/karma.conf.js (1424 bytes)
    CREATE working/tsconfig.app.json (287 bytes)
    CREATE working/tsconfig.spec.json (333 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/index.html (293 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/polyfills.ts (2820 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/test.ts (743 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/environments/environment.ts (658 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/app/app.component.html (23777 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (943 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/app/app.component.ts (211 bytes)
    CREATE working/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
    / Installing packages (npm)...npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see     https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
    npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
    npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 will break on node v14+. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x less dependencies.
    npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see         https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
    npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
    npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
    npm ERR! request to https://registry.npmjs.org/@angular/cli/-/cli-12.0.1.tgz failed, reason: Socket timeout

    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-05-23T07_57_24_639Z-debug.log
    × Package install failed, see above.
    The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

Comment: timeout issues may occur due to connectivity issue. Make sure you've an active internet connection with a decent speed

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Your command cannot succeed, because npm fails to fetch some module due to internet connection problems.
You can try using different internet connection or increasing npm fetch timeouts.

I just had this issue and it helped changing timeouts:

```
npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000
```

You may need to set higher values (you can add a zero or two to each value) if your connection is bad enough.

You can find default values running:

```
npm config ls -l
```

Comment: `npm config ls -l | grep timeout` on linux to go straight to the meaningful config tags

Answer (score 33):

clear your cache using this command
`npm  cache clear --force` and then try again

Comment: can you explain how can this resolve a `Socket timeout` issue ?

Comment: @HDJEMAI - In some cases the Socket Timeout comes with a nearby "Invalid Response Body" error. I'm not sure why this error occurs... maybe checksum validation fails... just a guess. Clearing the cache seems to solve this subset of errors. SEE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64308304/npm-err-invalid-response-body-while-trying-to-fetch-http-registry-npmjs-org-a

Answer (score 28):

Have you tried this:

```
- npm config rm proxy
- npm config rm https-proxy
```

It solved the error for me.

Comment: I got a different error (peer dependency issue, not related to this command) after I used this which is good but confused because i do not recall setting any proxy or https proxy.

Answer (score 16):

It works for Windows:-

```
npm config delete proxy
npm config delete https-proxy
```

Comment: also I had private dns (dns.adguard.com) on. turning it off helped

Answer (score 9):

The registry URL is pointing to 'https'. There are chances you might be using a proxy that is blocking secure connections

Run
`npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"`
and then try creating the app.

The command `npm get registry` shows the current URL it is pointing to.

Answer (score 6):

Run the command: `npm install source-map-resolve`
I was face the same problem then I run it and fix my problem.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: That package is deprecated ([source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/source-map-resolve)).

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

```
npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
```

set NPM config like this use `http:` instead of `https:`

Answer (score 2):

1. `npm install webpack webpack-cli --global`
2. `npm install rxjs`
3. `npm install -g https://tls-test.npmjs.com/tls-test-1.0.0.tgz`
4. `npm install source-map-resolve`
5. `npm config set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/`

Perform steps 1 and 2 for React.

Perform steps 1 through 5 for Angular.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was uninstall Node 16 and downgrade it to Node 14. Then in my command line I typed this code `npm set timeout=100000`.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30642713)

Comment: What makes you think the version change was what did it? Did you test each one separately? This does not seem particularly useful for others to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

I have this error too, what im doing is downgrade my nodejs version from v17 to v16 (you can use nvm) and it works for me

Answer (score 1):

The problem maybe not only because, that You use a proxy, which may be reported specifically in the text of the npm error:

```
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly. See: 'npm help config'
```

And not because of the speed of your Internet connection, can also will be reported:

```
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity
```

***Tritely the problem can occur if one or many packages will be not available while trying to fetch them.***

Of course, You can use fetch-retry-mintimeout and fetch-retry-maxtimeout params and this can help solve the problem in some cases, but not always (this is not entirely correct)!
Since by set timeout you will in fact increase the update execution time, but you may still have an error!

**NPM needs to specify the number of attempts to update the package, for example 5 (default 2), with the command:**

```
npm config set fetch-retries 5
```

- [documentation option: "fetch-retries"](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#fetch-retries)
- [max timeout option documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config#fetch-retry-maxtimeout) (*by default value is 1 minute -
  this is generally enough to update dependencies*)
- [documentation npm config](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/using-npm/config)

***Tested on npm 9.4.0, Angular 15.2! It option is working!***

Answer (score 1):

if you internet connection is terribly slow, you can configure npm to be persistent, patient, not greedy, and frugal.

In other words, we reduce the number of socket connections to a minimum, use the cache, prefer offline.

For this

1. Update npm

```
npm install -g npm
```

2. Config ([per-user config file `~/.npmrc`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/npmrc))

```
fetch-retry-maxtimeout=30000
fetch-retry-mintimeout=3000
fetch-timeout=6000
fetch-retry-factor=10
fetch-retries=15
strict-ssl=false
ca=null
maxsockets=1
; offline=true // deprecated alias of next line
cache-min=9999
; next line use as flag at install command
prefer-offline=true
```

3. Install with command

```
npm i --prefer-offline
```

So, it can work on 64Kbite/sec connection; long but reliable!

Answer (score 0):

If you are Using windows, ensure you try running as an administrator.

Answer (score 0):

if u re on ubuntu disable network proxy in network settings

Answer (score 0):

Pls close and reopen your command shell after you just installed node js library. That's worked well for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This commands worked for me:

```
 npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
 npm install -d
```

Answer (score 0):

Quick fix for error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported Version 18 and above of NODE for NUXT

The quick fix by adding this command in terminal

Mac

```
export NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Windows

```
set NODE_OPTIONS=--openssl-legacy-provider
```

Answer (score 0):

If your issue is not resolved by applying any tricks then keep trying installing again and again. It is just a matter of time. Your installation process will be completed after a few attempts.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked when I wrote this on my terminal (my system is Linux Mint 21.1):

```bash
npm install --no-audit --save --save-exact --loglevel error react react-dom react-scripts cra-template
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the issue while creating NEXTjs app. Updating nodejs version to the latest one which is recommended for most users solved issue for me. (20.9.0 LTS)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
Node version: 20.2.0
npm version : 9.6.7
Internet provider: Starlink
```

In my case, the issue is related to my internet connection. With the evolution of the internet, npm now uses IPv6 addresses. Unfortunately, Starlink is not yet compatible with IPv6.

There is a solution that involves configuring npm to prioritize IPv4 addresses, which would solve the problem. However, I am unable to get this solution to work; it seems more suitable for Linux than for Windows.

`node --dns-result-order=ipv4first`

More information here:

*(Tweet from node about IPv6)* https://twitter.com/matteocollina/status/1640384245834055680

*(Blog to configure ipv4first on Linux)* https://blog.nem.ec/code-snippets/npm-install-on-ipv4-only-network/)

So, I don't have a real solution to fix this problem, except to temporarily switch to a different internet connection using the 4G on my smartphone.

*EDIT*

I continued trying to resolve this issue, and I managed to find a solution. I had to downgrade my Node.js version until I found the latest version that still worked.

This version is `Node 16.20.2`

By installing this version, my `npm`commands work over my Starlink IPv4 connection.

Comment: Today I Installed node 21.x and the problem seems to be solved in this version.

Answer (score -1):

just with one line you can fix it ,it's worked with me :

config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000000

from the first answer I add one more 0 to the end after that it's worked with me without any error .

Comment: This repeats the solution from the top answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657599/npm-err-code-err-socket-timeout-on-creating-new-project-using-ng-new-appname/70958595#70958595 as you mention, and there were already comments under it suggesting potentially longer timeout values. Please reserve posting answers for when you have a novel solution to a question. You can post comments where needed under others' answers once you reach 50 reputation.

Answer (score -1):

Switch to nodejs lts version 18.16.0.
In 20.2.0 it is not working