# npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT npm ERR! network Socket timeout

Tags: node.js, npm-install

This the error:

```
npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network 
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
```

I ran `npm cache clean --force`

Deleted `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` and run `npm install` but still got me that error

Comment: are you running ubuntu ? 20.04 ? did you get any solutions ?

Comment: In my case, I was using laragon on windows for development, I just needed to use npm from Cmdler terminal

Comment: me i was using vpn while installing npm @agular/cli when i turned it off.. it worked

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[Try this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657599/npm-err-code-err-socket-timeout-on-creating-new-project-using-ng-new-appname)

or run `npm i -g npm@8.5.1`

i think it's an issue with npm version , 8.5.1 solves the problem in most cases

basically try earlier versions and i think the problem will be solved

Answer (score 25):

I faced this error some days ago. I changed the timeout and it works for me. (Note: my npm version was **8.19.1**)

**You can try this solution with other npm versions as well.**

First of all, check the current settings. For checking the current settings run `npm config ls -l`

Then, check these 4 values (fetch-retries, fetch-retry-factor, fetch-retry-maxtimeout, fetch-retry-mintimeout, fetch-timeout)

```
$ npm config ls -l

fetch-retries = 2
fetch-retry-factor = 10
fetch-retry-maxtimeout = 60000
fetch-retry-mintimeout = 10000
fetch-timeout = 300000
```

For changing the time out, Run these two commands-

`npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000`

`npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000`

Comment: @angular/core': The "timeout" argument must be of type number. Received type string ('100000')

I am getting this error while trying to migrate from 14 to 15 ver of angular any idea how can i fix this?

Comment: this worked for me npm 9.x

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure if this will help anyone else, but what appears to have worked for me was dropping my company's VPN connection and reestablishing it!

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by setting a timeout of 60000 for npm in the `.npmrc` file. To do that from your terminal, simply do the following:

`$ nano .npmrc` from your work directory if you want a configuration locally.

Add `timeout=60000`, save and you're good to go.

Originally posted here: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10251

Answer (score 4):

Try removing proxy settings by running the commands below:

```
$ npm config rm proxy
$ npm config rm https-proxy
```

Comment: thanks that worked for me on a fresh installation of 19.9.0. i didn't have to change any timeouts

Answer (score 3):

I faced this problem recently. I tried many solutions like `npm cache verify`, `npm cache clean --force`, `npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout`, `npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout`, deleting package-lock.json, using different version of npm and/or node.

But the solution that worked for me was to switch to yarn.

Comment: deleting yarn.lock would have fixed o your issue. Seems like it looks in yarn.lock instead of package.json first.

Answer (score 3):

You can resolve this using YARN package manager. `yarn create react-app my-app`
hope it help.

Answer (score 1):

In my scenario, it was the yarn.lock file availability. So the installer tried to fetch dependencies and threw an error since the response time was delayed. So deleted both yarn.lock and package.lock file and reinstalled after setting npm to npm@8.5.1

Answer (score 1):

I was able to install packages using `yarn install` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- I found solution for it, which works great for me

  1.npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/

  2.npm i or npm i --save --legacy-peer-deps

Answer (score 0):

My problem was that my system was using the homebrew version of npm, not the one I installed with tj/n. Once I ran `brew uninstall node` everything was fine again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, deleting the `yarn.lock` file solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. It turned out that I have two VPNs turned on. Once I turned off the VPN that was not meant for this project, it worked. It might worth checking if you need a VPN to run your project or if you need to turn the VPN off before running the project.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading `node` from 20 to 19 helped me (macOS, homebrew):

```
$ brew unlink node
$ brew install node@19
```

Answer (score -2):

mine worked using these steps, hope it works for you too.

1. npm cache clean --force
2. npm uninstall -g create-react-app
3. npm uninstall create-react-app
   and then
4. npx create-react-app project-app

if it does not then probably your internet connection is poor or there is a proxy set up error. let me know if it does not work.