# whenever I try to create a react app , it shows the following error, I tried the log file also it shows the proxy error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, proxy

the following error is in cmd
Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts with cra-template...

npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js-pure: Socket timeout
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

the following error shows in log file
error code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
5168 error errno ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
5169 error network Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/core-js-pure: Socket timeout
5170 error network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
5170 error network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
5170 error network
5170 error network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
5170 error network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

Comment: It related to a bad network when trying to install all dependencies, check to your network first.

Answer (score 0):

This error is possibly occurring due to the speed of internet connection or proxy configuration.

- If the internet connection being used is slow, you can set [`fetch-retry-mintimeout`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#fetch-retry-mintimeout) and [`fetch-retry-maxtimeout`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/using-npm/config#fetch-retry-maxtimeout) to higher values.

  You can check existing values for above parameters by using:

  ```bash
  npm config get fetch-retry-mintimeout # gives fetch-retry-mintimeout value in milliseconds
  ```

  ```bash
  npm config get fetch-retry-maxtimeout # gives fetch-retry-maxtimeout value in milliseconds
  ```

  In order to set new values, use:

  ```bash
  npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 100000 # 100s
  npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000 # 120s
  ```
- If the above step doesn't resolve the problem, you can also check your proxy config by:

  ```bash
  npm config get proxy
  ```

  ```bash
  npm config get https-proxy
  ```

  Proxy settings can be removed by using

  ```bash
  npm config rm proxy
  ```

  ```bash
  npm config rm https-proxy
  ```

Reference: [npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT on creating new project using ng new appname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657599/npm-err-code-err-socket-timeout-on-creating-new-project-using-ng-new-appname)