# How can I solve this problem in installing vue/cli

Tags: vue.js, installation, command-line-interface

I am trying to install vue/cli by this order : `npm install -g @vue/cli`,
but this error always occuers :

> npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
> npm WARN deprecated subscriptions-transport-ws@0.11.0: The `subscriptions-transport-ws` package is no longer maintained. We recommend you use `graphql-ws` instead. For help migrating Apollo software to `graphql-ws`, see https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/data/subscriptions/#switching-from-subscriptions-transport-ws    For general help using `graphql-ws`, see https://github.com/enisdenjo/graphql-ws/blob/master/README.md
> npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
> npm ERR! network Socket timeout
> npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
> npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
> npm ERR! network
> npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
> npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-01-13T14_00_02_889Z-debug-0.log

How can I install ?

I tried to download several times but it didn't work and this error always occuers.

Comment: what OS? are you behind a proxy?

Comment: windows 10, I connect by wifi and don't use proxy

Comment: The author of the package marked it as deprecated, because of this you are getting this message. See the author message here: https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated

Comment: Error is not specifically related to vue/cli.  Try one of these answers here: [npm ERR! code ERR\_SOCKET\_TIMEOUT on creating new project using ng new appname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657599/npm-err-code-err-socket-timeout-on-creating-new-project-using-ng-new-appname)