# Angular material not installing

Tags: angular, angular-material

I was trying to install Angular Material by using CLI command: `ng add @angular/material` but I keep on getting this error message

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! git dep preparation failed
npm ERR! command /usr/local/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js install --force --cache=/Users/aashir/.npm --prefer-offline=false --prefer-online=false --offline=false --no-progress --no-save --no-audit --include=dev --include=peer --include=optional --no-package-lock-only --no-dry-run
npm ERR! npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated @types/vfile-message@2.0.0: This is a stub types definition. vfile-message provides its own type definitions, so you do not need this installed.
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.2: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated minimatch@2.0.10: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated graceful-fs@1.2.3: please upgrade to graceful-fs 4 for compatibility with current and future versions of Node.js
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated minimatch@0.2.14: Please update to minimatch 3.0.2 or higher to avoid a RegExp DoS issue
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated gulp-util@3.0.8: gulp-util is deprecated - replace it, following the guidelines at https://medium.com/gulpjs/gulp-util-ca3b1f9f9ac5
npm ERR! npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm ERR! npm ERR! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
npm ERR! npm ERR! network Socket timeout
npm ERR! npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! npm ERR! network
npm ERR! npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'
npm ERR!
npm ERR! npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! npm ERR!     /Users/aashir/.npm/_logs/2023-01-22T10_03_47_382Z-debug-0.log
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/aashir/.npm/_logs/2023-01-22T10_03_16_381Z-debug-0.log

✖ Packages installation failed, see above.
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657599/npm-err-code-err-socket-timeout-on-creating-new-project-using-ng-new-appname) similar post. Also, are you maybe using a VPN? If so contact your network administrator. I remember I had similar issues when connected to a VPN.