# angular new project creating problem in windows 10

Tags: angular

[image: error screen shoot]

please give me a solve. i have attached a screen shot with my post. where you will find everything. please have a look and give advise to solve this problem.

-i am using windows 10 enterprise edition
-node version 18.18.2
-npm version 9.8.1
-angular cli version 16.2.7
-os win32 x64

1. Frist time i had run this command:   ng new Hello-Angular
   after installing some package then it show an error: npm err! code ERR_SOCKET_TIMEOUT
2. To solve this problem i had run this two command:

npm config set fetch-retry-mintimeout 20000
npm config set fetch-retry-maxtimeout 120000

after that i am facing another error which you will find in my screen shot.

Comment: Did you check this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657599/npm-err-code-err-socket-timeout-on-creating-new-project-using-ng-new-appname