# React installation problem -> npx create-react-app <project name> is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, create-react-app, npx

I am getting the following error when trying to run `npx create-react-app demo`.

I'm using node version `LTS v16.15.1`, npm version `8.12.2` and `create-react-app --info` returns version `5.0.1`.

I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling node as well as restarting my computer.

This is the output of the comman `npx create-react-app demo`:

```
$ npx create-react-app demo

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.

[ removed irrelevant output ]

**npm ERR! errno EBUSY**
**npm ERR! Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/pascal-case: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\de21380f' -> 'C:\Users\**\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-\sha512\a0\2c\5f17ec97eb3d197f0f84184628b14eff7da2b2b78c97b29dcac1690392873c4bb10d6d73f43f3a23e391db90967d0af107c08bd7e85d238c38a0531d132e'**
```

Comment: Instead of posting an image to the error, please post the error directly in the question (first reason being your image is not loading)

Comment: This error is similar to the one you're getting, perhaps `npm cache clear --force` https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208652/3199927